# Deleted partitions - grub rescue

Tags: grubrescue, usb-installation

I have deleted accidentally all disks partitions in the laptop, and now I cannot start ubuntu neither start installation from usb.
After turning on laptop I get

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

typing `ls` I get

```
(hd0)(hd1)
```

I don't need to recover any data I would like to install new OS

Comment: Typing `set` I get:
`
boot =(hd0,msdos5)
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5
`
I tried to
`
set boot=(hd0,msdos5)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
insmod normal -> get -> no such partition
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mand now I cannot start ubuntu neither start installation from usb. After turning on laptop I get...
>
> ```
> error: no such partition.
> Entering rescue mode...
> grub rescue>
> ```

When you reach grub rescue you are too late. During a boot you need to press a key (it differs for diff. BIOS; but ESC, F2, F8, F9, F10 are often used) to either enter bios where you pick your usb to boot from or to get a boot menu where you pick your USB to boot from.